# A grand split fairly

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

> My prefix says it's only a letter,
>   my infix with mas, gravel travelling,
>   my primefixes crushed orange into green,
>   I'll see it through, to make it get better.

Comment: The infix is fine, but I missed a letter in line 2 and not sure how to fix. Will leave and add bounty for correct ans or a fix for line 2.

Comment: Weirdly, I think I know the answer but cannot fit the second line.

Comment: @hexomino, I will accept without line 2 explanation. I made a change to it just before posting as I thought saw a nice fit, but my spelling of a word which has over two trillion hits in google was incorrect. There is some switching and double-duty going on I think, and I omitted a word which would have made this line easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, so I think the answer is

> [D:Ream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_Ream)

Title

> D is the Roman numeral for 500 and a ream is 500 sheets of paper so the answer could be read as 500:500 - a fair split of a grand (1000)

My prefix says it's only a letter,

> **Dre** - possibly a reference to Dr. Dre who has a song title "Nuthin' but a 'G' Thang".

my infix with mas, gravel travelling,

> **Rea** - I think this refers to **Chris** Rea ("mas" indicating Chris(t)mas) who is quintessentially "gravel-voiced". He also has the popular song "Driving Home for Christmas".

my primefixes crushed orange into green,

> If we take the 2nd, 3rd and 5th letters we get **R.E.M.** who had a song "Orange Crush" on the album "Green"

I'll see it through, to make it get better.

> These are hints to lyrics from the song "Things can only get better" by the band D:Ream.

Comment: @Tom Ah, okay, maybe I've got something now, I've tried to rewrite to fit a general theme.

Comment: Wonderful,one of the infix's works is popular at that time - can't believe my spelling.